# Why $x^Tx>x^Tz$ with high probability, for independent standard normal high dimensional vectors $x$ and $z$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

Let's say we sample two random vectors from the same multivariate Gaussian distribution $N(0, I)$. We are interested in the relationship between $x^Tx$ and $x^Tz$.

At first, I thought this question is purely wasting time because, for a sampled vector $x$, we can easily construct different $z$ that can be legally sampled, to make any of the three signs ($>$, $<$ or $=$) holds.

However, my simulation surprised me. For millions of random seeds with the vector length equals to 100, $x^Tx>x^Tz$. It looks like this is a guaranteed behavior while we all know it's not.

I wonder if there could be any explanation from the statistics point of view, like something stating the unlikeliness of sampling out a $z$ that can make $x^Tx<x^Tz$?

Please forgive me if you think this question is silly. But try it with your favorite programming language, you may come back to upvote me.

Comment: Are x and z independent random variables, both from normal distributions with means of zero and standard deviations of 1?  Notice that uTv measures the correlation between u and v,  so xTx will be larger than xTz because x is perfectly correlated with itself but less so with z.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "multivariate Gaussian distribution," but extrapolating this idea into $\mathbb R^2$, it makes perfect sense. $x^Tx = x \cdot x = \left\|x\right\|^2 cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. Indeed, $x^T$ is perpendicular to $x$, so $cos(\theta)$ should be maximized, and $x^Tx \ge x^Tz$ should always hold, assuming all sampled vectors are of the same length.

Comment: @BlakeSplitter "$x^T$ is perpendicular to $x$..." was the real insight for me mulling this question over! I wonder if this idea could be generalized this to an answer to all types of inner products and not just the familiar dot product for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @BlakeSplitter Thanks. But your explanation only makes perfect sense when ||x||=||z||, isn't it? Does it hold with high probability?

Comment: @BlakeSplitter "$x^T$ is perpendicular to $x$" ?? Sorry but what on Earth are you talking about?

Comment: HaohanWang: Your last comment should be addressed to @Andrew.

Comment: Oh I do apologize. $x^T$ is not perpendicular to $x$. Real brain fart there. What I meant was that $x$ is always parallel to itself, so since cosine is maximized when the angle between vectors is zero, $x \cdot x \ge x \cdot z$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y = X^T X - X^T Z$. We can write $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ where $Y_i = X_i (X_i - Z_i)$ are independent; $Y_i$ has mean $1$ and variance $3$.
By the Law of Large Numbers, when $n$ is large $Y/n$ has high probability to be close to the mean $1$.

For example, for $n=100$, $Y/n$ has mean $1$ and standard deviation
$\sqrt{3}/10 \approx 0.1732$.  $0$ is about $5.7735$ standard deviations from the mean, so the probability that $Y < 0$ is going to be quite small.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain a little bit more why the mean is 1?

Comment: $\mathbb E[Y_i] = E[X_i^2] - E[XZ] = 1 - 0 = 1$.